# Question on meromorphic functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm trying to do this optative exercise from my complex analysis course:

> Check if series $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{z-\pi k}\right)^2$$ converges for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ to a meromorphic function $f_1(z)$, so that if we consider the function $$f(z)=\frac{1}{\sin^2 z}$$ then $g(z)=f(z)-f_1(z)$ is an entire function.

This exercise is way harder than the previous ones I've done and don't know how to approach it. I don't know if I should find $f_1(z)$ first or there's a way to prove the result without finding it.

Thanks for the time and suggestions.

Comment: Iirc one may do the 'hardcore' direct evaluation with the residue calculus, a classic cosecant (or possibly cotangent) contour integral. This question implies one can deduce the result without explicit calculation, though

Comment: It is immediate that the poles of $f_1$ are at $\pi \Bbb{Z}$, same for the poles of $f$. Obviously $f_1(z)-\frac1{(z-\pi k)^2}$ is analytic at $\pi k$. It remains to check that the same holds for $f(z)-\frac1{(z-\pi k)^2}$, from which $f-f_1$ is analytic at $\pi k$. Since this holds for every $k$ it means that $f-f_1$ is entire.

Comment: @reuns Could you make that comment into an answer?  If you don't have time to flesh it out I will post a CW answer with the same content.

Comment: @reuns thanks for the reply. How can you prove that $f - f_1$ is analytic without having it explicitly defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sketch for the proof:** you need to check two things:

- That $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac1{(z-\pi k)^2}$ converges local uniformly in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \pi \mathbb{Z}$ and that it is differentiable (that is, you need to show that the series defines a holomorphic function in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \pi \mathbb{Z}$).
- That $\lim_{z\to w}\left(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac1{(z-\pi k)^2}-\frac1{\sin ^2 z}\right)\in \mathbb{C}$ for every $w\in \pi \mathbb{Z}$.

For the first point above you can notice that

$$
\frac{d}{d z}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac1{(z-\pi k)^2}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{d}{d z}\frac1{(z-\pi k)^2}
$$

as the RHS converges locally uniformly for any chosen $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \pi \mathbb{Z}$. To show the second point above, as the series $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac1{(z-\pi k)^2}$ defines a $\pi$-periodic function, it is enough to show that
$$
\lim_{z\to 0}\left(\frac1{z^2}-\frac1{\sin ^2 z}\right)\in \mathbb{C}
$$